# Frequency of Macbook fan sound

Tags: audio

My macbook spins off the fan like crazy which is audible when I'm recording a video when I show some stuff in Photoshop for instance. I'm thinking I could try to filter it out in Premiere Pro with high/low pass filters or an equalizer and I'm wondering what frequency might that sound of the fan have?

Anyone tried to remove the fan sound with this method or maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Screen recording definitely taxes laptop graphics cards and makes the fans whir. There's no easy way to avoid that.  I would instead try to use a mic that gets as close to your lips as possible (without popping), and move the laptop as far from your mouth as possible (external monitor / keyboard / mouse). The results will be better than trying to use noise reduction to improve the audio afterwards.  Noise follows an [inverse square law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law), so a small increase in distance from your lips will result in a big decrease in noise, if your mic is much closer to the desirable source than it is to the undesirable source.